# How attributes for NSAttributedString can __bridge from CoreText (CTFontRef, ...)?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsattributedstring, core-text, core-foundation

I need to convert a project to ARC.

Project is targeting iOS 7.0, and uses `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"foo" attributes:aDic]` with most attributes from CoreText.

```
NSDictionary *aDic = @{(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName: (id)ctFont,
                       (NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName: (id)ctParagraphStyle,
                       (NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: (id)[UIColor red].CGColor,
                       (NSString*)kCTKernAttributeName: @-0.5f};
```

1. How to I bridge the values correctly?

   - `(__bridge id)ctFont` or `(__bridge UIFont*)ctFont` or `(UIFont *)CFBridgingRelease(ctFont)`
   - `(__bridge id)ctParagraphStyle` or `(__bridge NSParagraphStyle*)ctParagraphStyle` or `(NSParagraphStyle *)CFBridgingRelease(ctParagraphStyle)`
   - `(__bridge id)[UIColor red].CGColor` or `(__bridge UIColor*)[UIColor red].CGColor` or `(UIColor *)CFBridgingRelease([UIColor red].CGColor)`
2. I noticed on my iOS9 device that some attributes, like `kCTKernAttributeName`, accept indifferently a documented `CFNumberRef` and an undocumented NSNumber*.

   - Is this compatibility the same on iOS 7 as well?
   - Is this compatibility available for CGColorRef/UIColor, CTFontRef/UIFont, CTParagraphStyleRef/NSParagraphStyle, ...?